# Problem in Subset settings of a list with javascript

Tags: javascript

I ran into a problem in a practice project

Inside the #java_script code to open and close a subcategory; I wrote some code, but the problem I have is that the first time I click on the location, which is activated with "On click"; When I click, it does not show any reaction

But the next time the problem will be completely solved until the page is refreshed again

And this problem exists for both "On click" that I have written so far separately

I put the javascript code and its github address; Thank you for your guidance

GitHub address:

https://github.com/A7337li/Demo-DigiKala

Javascript code text:

```
const $ = document;

function myfunction(colorText, subset, angleDown, angleUp) {

    let angleD = $.querySelector(angleDown).style.display;
    
    if (angleD == "inline") {
        $.querySelector(colorText).style.color = "red";
        $.querySelector(subset).style.display = "inline";
        $.querySelector(angleDown).style.display = "none";
        $.querySelector(angleUp).style.display = "inline";
    } else {
        $.querySelector(colorText).style.color = "black";
        $.querySelector(subset).style.display = "none";
        $.querySelector(angleDown).style.display = "inline";
        $.querySelector(angleUp).style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: That’s the function; what about the associated HTML and how the function is used?

Comment: 2 lines of HTML code related to this function; Lines 102 and 125 are HTML files that you can see in the following address: *** https://github.com/A7337li/Demo-DigiKala/blob/master/index.html

Comment: In a list, we have a title that has subcategories. By clicking on the title or the entire horizontal line in which the title is located, the function will be called with its arguments. If the "angle down" is active and visible, the first part of the "If" is executed, otherwise the second part of the code is executed.

Comment: The tasks that the function does in the first part of "if" are:  1- Changes the color of the title from black to red.   2- It changes the subset from non-displayable to displayable     3- The down angle changes from visible to invisible    3- The up angle changes from invisible to visible       ***    And in the "else" part, they all return to the previous state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to solve the problem myself

The problem was solved by changing the condition of "if" and moving the content of "if" and "else".

Modified code from the code above:

```
if (angleD == "none") {
        $.querySelector(colorText).style.color = "black";
        $.querySelector(subset).style.display = "none";
        $.querySelector(angleDown).style.display = "inline";
        $.querySelector(angleUp).style.display = "none";
    } else {
        $.querySelector(colorText).style.color = "red";
        $.querySelector(subset).style.display = "inline";
        $.querySelector(angleDown).style.display = "none";
        $.querySelector(angleUp).style.display = "inline";
    }
```

In the previous code, the condition in "if" was true, so "if" was executed first and then "else"; But in the performance, I would face the problem I said.

But with the new changes and shifting of "if" and "else" content and "if" conditions;

It is executed quickly without any conditions, and from the place where the "if" condition is fulfilled in the contents of the "else", it is executed with the second click of the "if";